# Add a outer circular strip to donut pie chart

Tags: jquery, html, css, flot, pie-chart

I have been trying to built a donut pie chart that looks like this

main issue is the outer strip ..

how do i get this outer strip ..

Please point me in the right direction

[image]

I am trying to use flotchart but i am open to use any other suggestion if you can guide

this is what i have rid so far

```
<div id="report_score_summary" class="chart" style="height:303px;width:100%">
<script>
                    data_score_summary = [
                      { label: "Description Score", data: 20, color: '#BA2B6B' },
                      { label: "Image Score", data: 30, color: '#375EAB' },
                      { label: "Header Score", data: 50, color: '#4BB748' },
                      { label: "Content Score", data: 10, color: '#F6871E' },
                      { label: "Title Score", data: 18, color: '#E1DC3A' },
                      { label: "Free", data: 16, color: '#E6E5E3' }
                    ];


         $.plot(report_score_summary, data_score_summary, {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            innerRadius: 0.5,
            show: true
        }
    }
});

setCode([
    "$.plot('#report_score_summary', data_score_summary, {",
    "    series: {",
    "        pie: {",
    "            innerRadius: 0.5,",
    "            show: true",
    "        }",
    "    }",
    "});"
]);  
</script>   
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amritanshu/1sxj56r6/1/)

Comment: Could you add a working example of your code? This should be possible by overlaying a bordered div with border-radious: 50% on top of the chart

Comment: I'd b using an SVG here....

Comment: If there's a clear container element you can work with, I would use a psuedo-element to create the effect:  http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/pbOwpW

This is using static values, but if you post your code, I'm sure it can be made dynamic if needed (relative measures vs. the set px values in the example.

Comment: hey every one thanks for the input ..  I am working on making a fiddle for my code

Comment: Hi every one i have updated the jsfiddle above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could plot another donut, bigger with a larger inner hole and position it behind your plot, not more elegant but working without move to SVG (that I think could be a better choice)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="report_score_summary" class="chart" style="height:303px;width:100%;z-index:2;margin-top:75px;margin-left: 62px;">

</div>

 <div id="report_score_summary_outer" class="chart" style="height:453px;width:100%;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;z-index: 1;">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $.plot(report_score_summary_outer, data_score_summary, {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            innerRadius: 0.8,
      width: 0.1,
            show: true,
      label: {
                show: false
            }
        }
    },
  legend: {
        show: false
    }
});
```

[I updated your jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sxj56r6/14/)

Comment: that was a brilliant solution ....  thanks a lot .. i guess this was the only solution because for the unallocated segment of outer strip i wanted the different section ..  i updated your fiddle , to get the what exactly i needed.. Just one more favour can you tell how I can show some thing in the centre i.e hole of donut

Comment: You could set another div with an higher z-index to bring it to front like this https://jsfiddle.net/1sxj56r6/14/